# Obtain Innertext from Web Element with Variable Path - Selenium

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a VBA macro that I'm running in Excel 2016.  The macro brings back information from the internet using Chrome and Selenium WebDriver.  The macro iterates through several similar webpages, but some pages have a few more or less lines than others.  Hence, the XPath to the innertext I'm interested in varies slightly from page to page.  Here is a snippet of the source code for the element, it is the "242" that I'm trying to locate and extract.

```
<div ng-repeat="squarefootage in improvement.SquareFootage" class="ng-scope">
  <div>
    <span class="labelSquareFootage ng-binding">ATTACHED GARAGE AREA </span><span class="result ng-binding">242</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a workaround I'm just grabbing the entire source code for the page and then parsing it with `INSTR` to find what I'm looking for.  I was wondering if there was a more elegant method to find an element with a variable path?  Is there something in WebDriver that would work like

`WDriver.FindElementbyInnerHTML`

?

[Here is a link](http://maps.boco.solutions/propertysearch/) to the website, you can look at a few different addresses and see how the path changes from page (address) to page (next address).

Answer (score 0):

You could gather all nodes with matching class and loop until desired garage text found then take the nextSibling

```
Public Sub Demo()
    'Your code to get to page and enter address and search, open heading, then....
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    html.body.innerHTML = WDriver.PageSource

    Dim nodes As Object, node As Object, i As Long

    Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll(".labelSquareFootage")

    For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
        Set node = nodes.Item(i)
        If InStr(node.innerText, "ATTACHED GARAGE AREA") > 0 Then 
            Debug.Print node.NextSibling.innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i  
End Sub
```

---

For xpath, you could try

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'ATTACHED GARAGE AREA')]]/following-sibling::span
```

if the desired value is the next span node. This searches for the desired text in the `.innerText` then takes the `nextSibling` span.

[CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I haven't been able to successfully apply it, I think things vary too much from page to page.  I've added a link to the website. Perhaps you could take a look and see if you can get a method to work for several different addresses.

Comment: Try: 1703 CATO, 4125 AMBER STREET and 1761 ROCKIES COURT.  They each have different paths leading to the garage square footage.

Comment: I can see 1761 ROCKIES COURT LAFAYETTE  but no garage info, only parcel sq ft. Am I supposed to press something other than **Property—ownership, address and other property information** ?

Comment: Click the "Assessment" tab on the left and you should see "ATTACHED GARAGE AREA 
  1049".  Thanks for your effort!